# Owl Carousel Youtube Integration with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, youtube, owl-carousel

I have been looking for the best way to integrate a youtube video carousel into an Angularjs site, and this is the best route I came up with.

The issue is I cannot get the plugin working to display the carousel, but all other views and directives are working correctly, so I assume the issue is specific to the Owl Carousel Youtube Integration. What am I doing wrong?

The  tags show up in the chrome inspector, so it seems the directive is somewhat connected properly to the view. But only the 'Test Words' are displayed in the view, and not the Carousel.

Here are the relevant files:

Index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html ng-app="NickPerspectApp">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Directives/appDirectives.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="" style="">
    <h1><a style="cursor:pointer;" ui-sref="Home">Nick's Perspective</a></h1>
    <h1><a style="cursor:pointer;" ui-sref="About">About</a></h1>
    <h1><a style="cursor:pointer;" ui-sref="Contact">Contact</a></h1>
</div>

<div  class="" id="" style="">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Routes:

```
NickPerspectApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Home');

$stateProvider

  .state('Home', {
    url: "/Home",
    template: "<home-page></home-page>",
    controller: "appController"
  })

  .state('About', {
    url: "/About",
    template: "<about-page></about-page>",
    controller: "appController"
  })

  .state('Contact', {
    url: "/Contact",
    template: "<contact-page></contact-page>",
    controller: "appController"
  })

});
```

Directives:

```
NickPerspectApp.directive('homePage', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: true,
   templateUrl: '../../partials/home.html'
  };
});


NickPerspectApp.directive('aboutPage', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: true,
   templateUrl: '../../partials/about.html',
  };
});


NickPerspectApp.directive('contactPage', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: true,
   templateUrl: '../../partials/contact.html',
  };
});


NickPerspectApp.directive('owlCarousel', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var options = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
    $(element).owlCarousel(options);
   },
   replace: true,
  };
});
```

home.html:

```
<div>

   <owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{items:1, merge:true,loop:true,margin:10,video:true,lazyLoad:true,center:true,responsive:{600:{items:1}}}">

      <div class="item-video" data-merge="1"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ngz3KP2GW0k"></a></div>

   </owl-carousel>

   <p style="color:black;">Test Words</p> //This populates

</div>
```

Comment: looks like your templates can't be loaded, try to use templateUrl without "../../" prefix. I mean you should put them to another path, e.g. two folders up "partials/contact.html" and check if angular loads them

Comment: @top.dev The views work. The home.html file is sending 'Test Words' to the view, but not whats encapsulated within the <owl-carousel> tags

Comment: I created test app and it works
1. include http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css

and 

http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css

2. add 

.owl-carousel .item-video {
  height: 300px;
}

3. Use at leas two items in the list (probably due to beta)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! @top.dev